# Access AngularJS $scope from JQuery .get

Tags: jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.26 and JQuery 1.11.2. I need IE8 support, so instead of using $http.get from AngularJS, I'm using JQuery's $.get and will add the  jQuery ajaxTransport extension for IE8 support:

`{{ testText }}
...
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("appController", function($scope) {
    $scope.testText = "loading";
    $.get("http://www.apicallgoeshere.com").done(function(res) {
        $scope.testText = "loaded";
    });
});`

Unlike with $http.get, the above code does not change testText to "loaded." How do I update the model correctly from within the $.get?

Comment: $scope.$apply(function() {
$scope.testText = "loaded";
});

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggested using [$scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) will solve the problem.

Why it is happening is, angularjs updates the UI components via watches, which has callback methods registered when a value attached to the scope changes. But it will happen only when the change happens within a angular method([digest cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest)). In your case you are using jQuery ajax and is changing the scope variable but angularjs is unaware about it so the UI is not updated.

So we uses the [$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) method which will force run the watches associated with the scope.

---

But instead you could use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service provided by angularjs

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("appController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.testText = "loading";
    $http.get("http://www.apicallgoeshere.com").success(function (res) {
        $scope.testText = "loaded";
    });
});
```